# Evaluation order of Button's action

Tags: evaluation, button, scheduling

It looks like a basic issue but I haven't found an answer anywhere.

Please tell me why the behavior (after clicking) of this `Button`:

```
Button["X", Print@1; Pause@1; Print@2;]
    (*1 and 2 appear simultaneously after 1 sec*)
```

is different from the behavior of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> evaluation:

```
Print@1; Pause@1; Print@2;
    (*printing of 2 happens 1sec after 1*)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is because `Button` actions are calculated on a *preemptive link*, meaning they preempt any other evaluation, but are only allowed a certain amount of time to evaluate. That indicates:

> the front end sends one evaluation at a time **and waits for the result before continuing with its other work**
>
> - [Tutorial / Advanced Dynamic Functionality / Synchronous versus Asynchronous Dynamic Evaluations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#681967067)

So it can't display `1` because it is waiting for `Pause[1];Print[2]` to finish.

You can replicate the behavior of

```
Print@1; Pause@1; Print@2;
```

by adding the option `Method->"Queued"` to the `Button` arguments.

This ensures the actions are performed in the current queue and no time limit is enforced.

See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Button.html) under "Details and Options"

---

Further reading:

- [Working with Dynamic: Synchronization with EventActions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120397/5478)

Comment: A little more explanation to the OP: Most likely, the code that needs to be run for the new cells to be created and formatted needs to wait until the preemptive evaluation has finished.  This is why `1` and `2` seems to appear simultaneously after a pause of 1 second.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the added color.