# Asynchronous evaluation of a button's action

Tags: dynamic, button

What would be the best way to have the value of x update before the pause (or a similarly slow function) finishes executing?

```
x = 0; Dynamic[{x, Button["+1", x++; Pause[3]]}]
```

Comment: You need `, Method -> "Queued"` for `Button.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. When I was playing with Method->"Queued", I had the button action statements in the wrong order >.<

Comment: Do you happen to know if this type of thing is possible in an EventHandler's actions?

Comment: it looks like people are walking the same paths eventualy :) look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19809/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Indeed that is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the direction.