# InputField Insertion Point Movement

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, eventhandler

I am trying to make the Return Key move the insertion point to the end of the input field's text. Please see the example below for the problem I am facing. Namely, when the return key is pressed, the input field's text is updated but the insertion point is not moved.

```
DynamicModule[{thing = "foo"}, nb = EvaluationNotebook[];EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic@thing,String], {"ReturnKeyDown" :> (thing = thing <> "bar";SelectionMove[nb, Next, Word])}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out. It is basically the same problem described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19556/evaluation-order-of-buttons-action) and essentially answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19809/evaluation-order-control).

The actions in the EventHandler are calculated on the preemptive link. In order to make the EventHandler act as a Button when Method->"Queued", DynamicWrapper can be used:

```
DynamicModule[{thing="foo",returnkeydown=False},nb = EvaluationNotebook[];DynamicWrapper[EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[thing],String],{"ReturnKeyDown":>(thing= thing<>"bar";returnkeydown=True)}],If[returnkeydown,returnkeydown=False;SelectionMove[nb,Next,Word]],SynchronousUpdating->False]]
```