# Why do modules work when executed from a cell but have side effects when run from a button click action on a manipulate panel?

Tags: programming, manipulate

Consider the following module:

```
startBrowser[] := Module[{},
   $browserstatus = True;
   ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> DIRJAVA, ClassPath -> DIRBOTA];
   BROWSER = JavaNew["org.nilostep.botautil.BrowserFacade"];
   ];
```

and

```
stopBrowser[] := Module[{},
   $browserstatus = False;
   BROWSER@quitDriver[];
   UninstallJava[];
   BROWSER = Null;
   ];
```

and

```
controlPanel[]:=Manipulate[
 If[$browserstatus, color1 = Green, color1 = Red, color1 = Gray];
 Grid[{
   {"Browser ", Graphics[{color1, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20]},
   {"Hive ", Graphics[{color2, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20]
    }}],
 Button["Start Browser", startBrowser[];],
 Button["Stop Browser", stopBrowser[];],
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 Initialization :> {color1 = Gray, color2 = Gray}
]
```

Now, consider the following scenario:

```
controlPanel[]
```

the manipulate panel becomes, as expected, visual. Without clicking the buttons the browser is started and stopped as follows:

```
startBrowser[]
```

as a result the image in the panel changes from red to green and a Java- and browser instance can be seen in the Task Manager.

```
stopBrowser[]
```

as a result the image in the panel changes from green to red, the browser instance is killed after which the Java session is terminated.

Now, my question.

I expected that the same would happen when I click the buttons in the Manipulate program.

But when I click on the "Start Browser" button, a message appears with the text "One or more dynamic objects are taking excessively long, etc...". When I click "Continue Waiting" the button turns green and the Browser can be seen in Task Manager.

Then when I click the "Stop Browser" button, Java is uninstalled, but executing the quitDriver[] method on the BROWSER object failed.

I don't quite understand this behavior. How can I execute the start- and stop modules by buttons on the Manipulate panel?

Why do modules work when executed from a cell but have side effects when run from a button click action on a manipulate panel?

Comment: Do you think it is a valid duplicate: [**19556**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19556/5478)? Or [120397](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120397/5478)

Comment: I wouldn't have found it by the description although the explanation of both questions is the same. You look different at it when you already understand the difference between preemptive and queued.

Comment: Once the duplicate is marked it says "this question already has an answer in..." which makes more sense in this context.